# How to import data from CSV file that contains just one large row of data, into an array with separated values?

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I currently have a CSV file that contains voltage values from an oscilloscope. The data is stored in a singular row made up of 5000 cells, like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0...]
```

[screenshot of part of excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhe5H.png)

When I try to import the data into an array, it creates an array of index 1, containing all 5000 values in that first array[0] index. So when I print array[0], it shows all 5000 values, and when I print array[1-4999], an error occurs. How can I have each value from the cell in its own spot in the array?

Here is my code:

```
import csv

array = []

with open("test2.csv", 'r') as f:
    cols = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for r in cols:
        array.append([r])

print(array[0])
```

Comment: you data is in a single row or column? I see that you say row, want to make sure.

Comment: A single row made up of 5000 columns or cells.

Comment: Is that what you are trying to achieve for, "How can I have each value from the cell in its own spot in the array?"

Comment: Yes exactly that, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

array = []

with open("test2.csv", 'r') as f:
    cols = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    # r is a single element
    for r in cols:
        # loop through each item in r
        for i in r:
            # append each element as list element
            array.append([i])

print(array)
```

Ouput:

```
[['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['2'], ['4'], ['5']]
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much! I realize where I messed up now.